# EJB Container initialization error, Error while binding JNDI name *** for EJB ***

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, war, java-ee-7

I am new to Java and I developed a sample Java EE application that works with normal Java client, but it does not work with Servlets. I developed EE project in Netbeans IDE with an Application Client, EJB module and Web module.

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column (name="id")
private String id;
@Column (name="name")
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

**myBeanInterface.java**

```
import Entities.Customer;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
@Remote
public interface myBeanInterface {
    void addCustomer(Customer customer);    
}
```

**CustomerSession.java**

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerSession implements myBeanInterface {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Omazon-EJBPU")
EntityManager em;

@Override
public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    em.persist(customer);
}
```

**Java Client**

```
@EJB
private static myBeanInterface inter;
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    inter = (myBeanInterface) context.lookup("Session.myBeanInterface");
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId("16906");
    customer.setName("My book from Main");
    inter.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

**Servlet**

```
public class addCustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
public myBeanInterface myBean;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException , NamingException {


    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

    myBean = (myBeanInterface) context.lookup("Session.myBeanInterface");
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId("1198");
    customer.setName("i1787");
    myBean.addCustomer(customer);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet addCustomerServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet addCustomerServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
INFO:   file:/C:/Users/Irfan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestWeb/build/web/WEB- INF/lib/Omazon-EJB.jar_Omazon-EJBPU login successful
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name Session.myBeanInterface for EJB CustomerSession
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1552)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:190)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:63)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
... 38 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:322)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:257)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:640)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:4859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1539)
... 41 more

SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name Session.myBeanInterface for EJB CustomerSession
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1552)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:190)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:63)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
... 38 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:322)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:257)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:640)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:4859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1539)
... 41 more

SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   The web application [unknown] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1] (value [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1@2aa5b721]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] (value [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
INFO:   file:/C:/Users/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestWeb/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/Omazon-EJB.jar_Omazon-EJBPU logout successful
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name Session.myBeanInterface for EJB CustomerSession
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1552)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:190)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:63)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:322)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:257)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:640)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:4859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1539)
... 41 more
```

Comment: it seems to be that the exception was thrown at deploy time, try to be sure that your app is well packaged.
"Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override" this tell me that you are trying to deploy the ejb twice. Before fix your ejb clients code, you need to solve this exception.

Comment: Thanks, the problem i know what it says, but i don't know how to solve it. I used rebind, but the errors are same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem by finding a post on some forum which states:
**Disable GlassFish Server v2 Vendor-Specific JNDI Names**
The EJB 3.1 specification supported by GlassFish Server 3.1 defines portable EJB JNDI names. Because of this, there is less need to continue to use older vendor-specific JNDI names.

By default, GlassFish Server v2–specific JNDI names are applied automatically by GlassFish Server 3.1 for backward compatibility. 
However, this can lead to some ease-of-use issues. For example, deploying two different applications containing a Remote EJB component that exposes the same remote interface 
causes a conflict between the default JNDI names.

The default handling of v2–specific JNDI names in GlassFish Server 3.1 can be managed with the asadmin command or with the disable-nonportable-jndi-names boolean property for 
the ejb-container element in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml.

Use the asadmin command or directly modify the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file to set the disable-nonportable-jndi-names property.

Using the asadmin command:
**asadmin> set server.ejb-container.property.disable-nonportable-jndi-names="true"**

Directly modifying the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file.
Add the disable-nonportable-jndi-names property to the ejb-container element in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml.
Set the value of the disable-nonportable-jndi-names boolean, as desired.
false — Enables the automatic use of GlassFish Server v2–specific JNDI names. This is the default setting.

true — Disables the automatic use of v2–specific JNDI names. In all cases, 3.1-compatible JNDI names will be used.

Save the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file and restart the GlassFish Server domain.
This setting applies to all EJBs deployed to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I think it's still very important. The solution is quite easy, in the pom.xml file of the Servlet module you need to add the next text

`<scope>provided<scope>`

this is due because you already have deployed an EJB so when yo try to do it with servlet it will copy it generating the error