# Glassfish throws error on deploying the EJB

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, java-ee-8

I am trying to deploy the EJB on glassfish, but when I deploy - am being thrown an exception

```
 Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseApplication4]|#]
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [EnterpriseApplication4-ejb_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:73)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:797)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [EnterpriseApplication4-ejb_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:655)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:367)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:256)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.readModulesDescriptors(ApplicationArchivist.java:599)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:173)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3207)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3056)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:854)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:294)
    ... 52 more
|#]
  Exception while deploying the app [EnterpriseApplication4] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [EnterpriseApplication4-ejb_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [EnterpriseApplication4-ejb_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:655)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:367)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:256)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.readModulesDescriptors(ApplicationArchivist.java:599)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:73)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:797)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 22; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":entity, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-driven}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3207)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3056)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:854)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:294)
    ... 52 more
|#]
```

I have the following directory structure [![Directory Structure][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Px67.png

Following are the ejb-jar.xml which I think might be the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
  <enterprise-beans>
      
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Also is it mandatory that any state/stateless bean used be specified in the ejb-jar.xml?

Comment: ejb-jar.xml is optional in EJB 3.x, you can try removing this file. The file also says "ejb-jar version=2.1" which does not match the Java EE level. What is your Glassfish version?

Comment: @Lini Glassfish 5.1.0. But when I don't give an entry in the ejb-jar.xml, glassfish shoes that the enterprise-bean is not complete

Comment: what error do you get if you remove the file from project (since it is not needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments given @Lini was useful. I solved the problem by upgrading the ejb-jar.xml to 3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
```

But if this file is completed as shown the above trace, following error is thrown

```
The content of element 'enterprise-beans' is not complete
```

Once the above file is updated, I followed this answer to get the correct JNDI name from the server debug

[Disable GlassFish Server v2 Vendor-Specific JNDI Names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21321738/7113842)